# create a decision tree model

Tags: sas

I am trying to create a decision tree model. This is the error I get:

```
 1          OPTIONS NONOTES NOSTIMER NOSOURCE NOSYNTAXCHECK;
 72         
 73         WORK.IMPORT = New WORK.IMPORT (student, blanace, income);
            ___________
            180
 
 ERROR 180-322: Statement is not valid or it is used out of proper order.
 
 74         String name = map.get(WORK.IMPORT);
            ______
            180
 
 ERROR 180-322: Statement is not valid or it is used out of proper order.
 
 75         
 76         OPTIONS NONOTES NOSTIMER NOSOURCE NOSYNTAXCHECK;
 88
```

Here my sample code I have tried. Am I close at all?

```
WORK.IMPORT = New WORK.IMPORT (student, blanace, income);
String name = map.get(WORK.IMPORT);
```

New code:

```
proc logistic data = cleaned_anes descending;
  class default / param=glm;
  model default = student balance income;
run;
```

Error: I have invalid variables. Seems like I getting closer.

Comment: This is not SAS code.

Comment: I am struggling mightily.

Comment: You need to take some SAS programming courses to begin understanding the basics. SAS has free e-learning. There are hundreds of procedures for various statistical, ML, and data problems. I also recommend going to the SAS communities forum where people can help you with procedure-specific questions. There are people who are experts in literally one or two procedures because of how often they're used to solve common problems.